# Unexpected extra semicolon SonarQube

Tags: html, css, sonarqube

I encountered some strange behavior from SonarQube.
It shows that there is an extra semicolon somewhere.
[image]

Is this a malfunction of the scanner or can this code be corrected somehow?

[image]

Edit: Added SonarQube eplanation

Comment: Have you clicked on "Why is this an issue?" first of all, to see if there is any further explanation?

Comment: Yep, but I added a picture of it, especially for you

Comment: Is it getting confused by the - ? Is there still a problem if you encase the sans-serif say in double quotes?

Comment: @AHaworth after that change says "Unexpected missing generic font family"

Comment: Generic names are keywords, and _must_ not be quoted. What happens when you quote the family names instead? `font-family: "Verdana", "Geneva", sans-serif;` (Those should not actually need it, because they do not contain any spaces, but perhaps the tool is picky.)

Comment: @CBroe "Unexpected extra semicolon" unfortunately

Comment: So can you try just plain serif (I know that’s not what you want, anymore than you wanted sans-serif in quotes, but this is an effort to further pin down the problem)